# Very old Payne furnace blower motor hums but won't start

Tags: hvac, furnace

My mother has an old Payne furnace (20+ years old) and the blower motor is no longer kicking on all of a sudden. When the motor tries to start, it hums/buzzes pretty loudly, but won't kick on.

My thought was the run capacitor might be bad, which I removed and tested with my Fluke. It's showing 5 μF, which I believe is the correct capacitance, but it's hard to tell. The old capacitor looks pretty rough, and I can't read the label. The terminals are also pretty rusted. The capacitor has never been replaced, so it's easily 20+ years old too.

The bottom line is the whole system needs replaced. But I'm trying to limp her along until we have the money to do so. My first thought is to try replacing the capacitor anyway, but I wasn't sure if it's worth attempting if I'm reading 5 μF? Or if there is something else worth trying first?

Again, it does try to kick on (hums really loud), but doesn't blow. I'm hoping the motor isn't DOA, but given the age, I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: Good move with the capacitor, that’s what I would do. Also check if motor stuck (safely turn it a little).

Comment: Yes, agree with @PolypipeWrangler   make sure the fan turns freely.   Unfortunately, if it's been in that state for a while, it's entirely possible that the motor has over-heated and some of the windings have shorted out.  Nothing to be done about that other than replace the motor, if one is available that fits.  20 years old isn't all that old so there is a good chance one is available if needed.  But I'd start with replacing the capacitor if you can determine exactly what is needed.

Comment: I would apply 120VAC directly to the motor and see if it runs.   If not, you need a new motor.  If it does run....there is something else upstream...perhaps a relay/switch (they can hum but not operate).

Comment: Use the old but proven method. Motors always need help to start rotating. Use a wooden stick and make it turn as fast as you can, then remove the stick and turn on power.

Comment: The capacitor might be good, but rusted terminals are almost the same as being not connected.  Start with new capacitor and new ends on the wires.  Could try cleaning the terminals, 20 years it probably will not last long anyway.

Comment: Someone needs to make an answer out of these comments...